# Beta decay as electron source in vacuum tubes?

Tags: vacuum-tube

I've been thinking about this for a few days now, would this even be possible? There is another question like this being asked but via the photoelectric effect utilizing lasers. What if we used a nuclear electron source?

Wouldn't that help with the inefficiencies related to the heater with vacuum tubes?

Thanks

Comment: There are enough other reasons to not use vacuum tubes, I don't think heater inefficiency is the driving factor (search on "cold cathode vacuum tube").  And I think that if you made a cathode with material that was a strong enough beta emitter to be useful you would (A) not have a cathode for very long, (B) the cathode would self-heat more than enough to emit electrons, and very possibly (C) hanging out close to the vacuum tube would be lethal because of gamma-ray emission along with the beta rays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been used in some [Krytrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krytron)  to replace or supplement a separate electrode whose purpose is to pre-ionize some gas near the cathode to make formation of the main current-carrying arc faster.